# MySQL and PhP PayPal IPN Cart

Tags: mysql, paypal

Im trying to make a cart where on some items you can have attributes. All the code works except i can't pull the options from certain items.

PayPal IPN pull code:

```
$value_select = $_POST['os'.$j.'_'.$number];
```

The $j count is correct and $number is item id, but i it returns error saying it doesn't exist.

My HTML and PhP code:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="medievalpvp1060@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">  
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.littlemischiefs.co.uk/temp/api/ipn">
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="item test">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.20">
    Colour:
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="colour">
    <select name="os0">
    <option value="pink">pink</option>
    <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
    </select><br />
    Text Line 0:
    <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="text line 0">
    <input type="text" name="os1"><br />
    Text Line 2:
    <input type="hidden" name="on2" value="text line 2">
    <input type="text" name="os2"><br /><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="**************">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
</form>
```

Comment: The name of your input fields are os1 and os2. In $_POST you are using os1_itemid. Verify the name of your input.

Comment: Yes but what about if there are multiple items to process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed and this is how to do it for all those who need advice.

Using `os<param.catch>` (`os0`) would be the param of catcher param0.

FIX:

Use os0, os1, os2.. etc in html as a value code but make sure to call the on0 as a label e.g. `<input type="hidden" value="Anything here">`.

In your IPN call `$_POST['option_selection'.$paramcatch.'_'.$item_id]`

So e.g wanting data from item 1 and 2:

```
$_POST['option_selection0_1'] = os0 from item 1
$_POST['option_selection1_1'] = os1 from item 1
$_POST['option_selection2_1'] = os2 from item 1

$_POST['option_selection0_2'] = os0 from item 2
$_POST['option_selection1_2'] = os1 from item 2
$_POST['option_selection2_2'] = os2 from item 2
```

Hope this helped a lot of people! I have fixed my issue just wanted to help the rest of you!!

Thanks for your comments too!

Answer (score 1):

This code will make all of the order items available in a $cart_items array.

```
$i = 1;
$cart_items = array();   
while(isset($_POST['item_number' . $i]))   
{   
    $item_number = isset($_POST['item_number' . $i]) ? $_POST['item_number' . $i] : '';   
    $item_name = isset($_POST['item_name' . $i]) ? $_POST['item_name' . $i] : '';   
    $quantity = isset($_POST['quantity' . $i]) ? $_POST['quantity' . $i] : '';  
    $mc_gross = isset($_POST['mc_gross_' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_gross_' . $i] : 0;
    $mc_handling = isset($_POST['mc_handling' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_handling' . $i] : 0;
    $mc_shipping = isset($_POST['mc_shipping' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_shipping' . $i] : 0;
    $custom = isset($_POST['custom' . $i]) ? $_POST['custom' . $i] : '';   
    $option_name1 = isset($_POST['option_name1_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name1_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection1 = isset($_POST['option_selection1_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection1_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_name2 = isset($_POST['option_name2_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name2_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection2 = isset($_POST['option_selection2_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection2_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name3 = isset($_POST['option_name3_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name3_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection3 = isset($_POST['option_selection3_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection3_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name4 = isset($_POST['option_name4_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name4_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection4 = isset($_POST['option_selection4_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection4_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name5 = isset($_POST['option_name5_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name5_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection5 = isset($_POST['option_selection5_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection5_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name6 = isset($_POST['option_name6_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name6_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection6 = isset($_POST['option_selection6_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection6_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name7 = isset($_POST['option_name7_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name7_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection7 = isset($_POST['option_selection7_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection7_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name8 = isset($_POST['option_name8_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name8_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection8 = isset($_POST['option_selection8_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection8_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name9 = isset($_POST['option_name9_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name9_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection9 = isset($_POST['option_selection9_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection9_' . $i] : '';

    $btn_id = isset($_POST['btn_id' . $i]) ? $_POST['btn_id' . $i] : '';

    $current_item = array(   
                           'item_number' => $item_number,   
                           'item_name' => $item_name,   
                           'quantity' => $quantity, 
                           'mc_gross' => $mc_gross, 
                           'mc_handling' => $mc_handling, 
                           'mc_shipping' => $mc_shipping, 
                           'custom' => $custom,   
                           'option_name1' => $option_name1,   
                           'option_selection1' => $option_selection1,   
                           'option_name2' => $option_name2,   
                           'option_selection2' => $option_selection2, 
                           'option_name3' => $option_name3, 
                           'option_selection3' => $option_selection3, 
                           'option_name4' => $option_name4, 
                           'option_selection4' => $option_selection4, 
                           'option_name5' => $option_name5, 
                           'option_selection5' => $option_selection5, 
                           'option_name6' => $option_name6, 
                           'option_selection6' => $option_selection6, 
                           'option_name7' => $option_name7, 
                           'option_selection7' => $option_selection7, 
                           'option_name8' => $option_name8, 
                           'option_selection8' => $option_selection8, 
                           'option_name9' => $option_name9, 
                           'option_selection9' => $option_selection9, 
                           'btn_id' => $btn_id
                          );   

    array_push($cart_items, $current_item);   
    $i++;   
}
```